Add custom schedule to wordpress
I'm making a Wordpress plugin, where I would like to set a WordPress cronjob, based on a custom schedule that I'm making.
For some reason, it seems that I can't set my custom schedule.
I'm using the add_filter like this which it has to call the callback function add_custom_schedule but it seems that it is not calling the function at all.
Here is my code
<?php

// Form submission handling function
function handle_form_submission() {
    if (isset($_POST['save_fetch_settings'])) {
        $auto_fetch = isset($_POST['auto_fetch']) ? 1 : 0;
        
        if ($auto_fetch) {
            error_log('auto_fetch if'); 
            add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_custom_schedule');
        }
    }
}


function add_custom_schedule($schedules) {
    error_log('add_custom_schedule called'); // Debug statement

    $schedules['custom_seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __('Every 60 Seconds')
    );
    return $schedules;
}

The error_log('auto_fetch if') is printing normaly in my logs, so it enters the if.
The error_log('add_custom_schedule called') is not priting
I followed every step from Wordpress Developer Wiki but it doesn't work.
So, as you can see, I added the error_log to find out what is calling and what is not, and it seems that the function add_custom_schedule is not called at all.
In case that it helps, I'm also adding the function the creates the HTML form with the submit button with the post request save_fetch_settings
<?php

function plugin_settings_page_html() {
    $auto_fetch = get_option(AUTO_FETCH_OPTION, '');
    $minutes_auto_fetch = get_option(MINUTES_AUTO_FETCH_OPTION, '');
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>API Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <?php settings_fields('plugin_settings'); ?>
            <div style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; padding: 1px 15px 0px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <h2>Fetch Settings</h2>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row">Enable Auto-fetch Data</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="auto_fetch" value="1" <?php checked(get_option(AUTO_FETCH_OPTION), 1); ?>>Auto Fetch</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row">Minutes to Auto-fetch</th>
                        <td><input type="number" name="minutes_auto_fetch" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option(MINUTES_AUTO_FETCH_OPTION, 15)); ?>"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php submit_button('Save fetch settings', 'primary', 'save_fetch_settings'); ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

and the admin_init action which is in the main plugin file
// Hook the form submission handling function
add_action('admin_init', 'handle_form_submission');


So far you have only shown us functions, but where & when are those actually getting invoked?

I have created a form in the wordpress' backend with a submit_button, which sents a post request in save_fetch_settings
<?php submit_button('Save fetch settings', 'primary', 'save_fetch_settings'); ?>
Then the function that i posted above (handle_form_submission) is executed and enters the if (isset($_POST['save_fetch_settings'])) {}

That still doesn't really explain when handle_form_submission gets invoked. But either way, I don't think it makes sense to only try and add your interval, after your form has been submitted - add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_custom_schedule'); should simply be executed on every page load, without dependency on any conditions - so that the new interval actually exists already, at whatever point you will try to select it.

I edited the post and added more information if that is usefull to you. I will also think of what you told me and try to work with that. I was just thinking to create a form that would create a schedule, based on the timer that the user selected.

Following CBroe's suggestion, I have relocated the add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_custom_schedule'); outside the if condition. Consequently, it now runs with each page load and it works fine!
